# How do I write Swift infix functions?

Tags: swift, infix-notation

I've seen this done, but I just can't wrap my head around it. Somehow, seemingly magically, some infix functions work fine, but others simply won't compile. For example:

[image: A function named "*" works fine, but one named "then" does not.]

As you see here, my `then` function work as a traditional function, but not as an infix one, yet my `*` one has the opposite issue. **What's the magic sauce to get my `then` function to be an infix one?**

Side question: Why won't my `*` function work as a traditional function?

---

Code for text-only readers and copy-pasting:

```
public func * (let left:String, let right:Int) -> String {
    if right <= 0 {
        return ""
    }

    var result = left
    for _ in 1..<right {
        result += left
    }

    return result
}
*("Left", 6) // error: '*' is not a prefix unary operator
"Left" * 6   // "LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft"

public func then (let left:String, let _ right:String) -> String {
    return left + right
}
then("Left", "Right") // "LeftRight"
"Left" then "Right"   // 2 errors: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
```

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html at the infix operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Swift standard library already defines `*` as an infix operator:

```
infix operator * {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}
```

You'll find a list of the pre-defined operators in the
[Swift Standard Library Operators Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html). Alternatively, "command-click" on the `import Swift` statement in Xcode and search for "operator".

To use an operator in a "traditional" function call, you have to enclose it in parentheses:

```
(*)("Left", 6)
```

If you want to define your own infix operator, you have to add an
`infix operator` declaration. Note however, that only a restricted set of
characters is valid for operators (see [Language Reference->Lexical Structure->Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418) for the precise rules). In particular, an operator
name must (as @dfri already said) start with 
/, =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ?, ~, or some other "symbol" characters. In particular, "then" is not a valid operator name.

Comment: Great answer.  Where in the Swift standard lib are these infix operators declared?  I'd love to do through the modules and and take a look at how these work.

Comment: @JAL: For their declarations, Cmd-click `Swift` in `import Swift` in e.g. a playground.

Comment: @JAL: ... or here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html.

Comment: You mention "that only a restricted set of characters is valid". What characters are those? Also, where are they in the book?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero: dfri already provided a link and a quote from the reference in his answer, therefore I did not want to copy that.

Comment: @MartinR Feel free to add the character restrictions it into your answer if you deem it relevant; better to have all relevant information in one single answer.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is already defined, natively, as a binary infix operator in Swift:

```
infix operator * {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}
```

Hence, any function of the form `func * (...` is will be overloading this binary infix operator. On the other hand, if you attempt to use the `*` operator as a *prefix unary* operator, you will get the descriptive error that *"`*` is not an prefix unary operator"*, simply since `*` does not exist natively as a prefix operator.

You could of course define your own *prefix* operator `*`:

```
prefix operator * { }
prefix func * (rhs: Int) -> Int {
    return rhs*rhs
}

var a : Int = 2
var b : Int = *a // 4
```

To wrap this up: some operators exists natively in Swift both as prefix and infix operators, e.g. `-`

```
/* Declared natively in Swift */
infix operator - {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

prefix operator - {
}

/* Example usage */
let a : Int = 2 - 1 // 1,  '-' infix operator used
let b : Int = -1    // -1, '-' prefix operator used
```

whereas others, such as `*`, is just (natively) used as an infix operator.

Also note that if you want to define your own custom infix operators, their allowed names are constrained as follows:

> Custom operators can begin with one of the ASCII characters /, =, -,
>   +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ?, or ~, or one of the Unicode characters defined in the grammar below (which include characters from the
>   Mathematical Operators, Miscellaneous Symbols, and Dingbats Unicode
>   blocks, among others). After the first character, combining Unicode
>   characters are also allowed.

From [Language Reference - Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html).